# Visual Studio 2022 version 17.1.0 Update - Floating Windows no longer merge together to form a tabbed layout

Tags: visual-studio-2022

This is doing my nut in!

Simply updating VS 2022 to ver. 17.1.0 has broken the ability to drag the header of a floating window towards the header of another window and allow them to merge into one single floating window with a tabbed view layout.

This has ruined my productivity in being able to have multiple files open between a multi monitor layout. Is anyone aware of a option/setting that might have been disabled from the update?

The screenshot below shows where I would usually drag one floating window towards another an if i left go of the mouse in the right place, the two windows would usually snap tpgather into one window with multiple tabs:

[image]

Edit: Futher observations conclude the latest VS 17.1.0 have changed the way we can group floating windows together.

By default, my tabs are configured to display along the top, however the only way i can group together the windows is if i change the tab location from the TOP to the Side, but this changes the tab layout in the main IDE as well as floating windows, so it screws eveything up.

[image]

Merging the windows together:

[image]

[image]

Incidentally if I revert back to displaying the Tabs at the TOP, then we have the affect i wanted BUT I stil cannot merge any further windows in that mode:

[image]

Comment: I know this doesn't help your problem but this functionality still works on my VS2022 (17.1.0). Could there be some conflict with any extensions you are using? I don't know of any setting that controls this functionality. Have you tried launching VS in safe mode? What about repair or re-install?

Comment: Hi, Ive tried a VS repair so it reset everything back to factory settings but this hasnt fixed the issue. I didnt make any changes to either the project or my Windows 10 environement between the point where the previous version was working and the upgrade to 17.1 so I'm baffled what's causing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just occured to me that the you can snap together the floating windows into a tabbed view by dragging one window with the mouse over the top of another window and then you see the following icon appear:

[image]

If you then drag the window and move your mouse cursor over the center point of this icon set then it will in fact merge the two windows together into a tabbed view.

[image]

[image]

Well this wanst the most intelligent question I'd ever asked! I just hadnt done it this way before and the previous way in doing this had stopped working foo me since upgrading VS22 to latest 17.1.0 from 17.0.1